# get one file from each directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

in my app user can have multiple directory in setting , I want to get one file for each folder, note these directories can have their own directories an nested as possible 
my config.json

```
{"dirs":["F:/music/Ellie Goulding","F:/music/Eminem - Revival [Album] [iTunes Version] - [7tunes]"]}

var findSongs = async function (baseDir,isDir=false,musics)  {
  try{
    musics =musics || []
    var files = await getDirFiles(baseDir)

    for(let i =0;i<files.length;i++){
      try {
        let file = files[i]
        var musicPath = `${baseDir}/${file}`

        let stat = fs.lstatSync(musicPath)    
        if(stat.isDirectory()){
          await findSongs(musicPath,true,musics)
        }else{ 

        let meta = await getMusicMeta(musicPath)

        if(meta){
            musics.push(meta)
        }
        if(isDir){
          break
        }

    }
```

issue with this code is it goes get all songs of second folder and doesn't return anything from folder one but if only place one folder like this : F:/music it will work as expected

Comment: Note: be careful that Javascript is indulgent with missing `;` at the end of instructions where there is a new line.. but it's not a really good practice because your code will probably throw errors or unexpected results when minified, or with using the `return` keyword in special cases

Comment: The await findSongs(musicPath,true,musics)  could be the problem due to asynchronous call